# Logging under vaadin and spring

Tags: java, spring, logging, vaadin, vaadin7

need some help!
What is the most elegant way to log all user interactions like login menu changes or almost every click. I also want to log form datas as well, with a kind of annitation solution to slect the significant data ex. ID-s.

Can I use guava for that?

Comment: Did you try using pure Vaadin listeners like `clickListener` and `viewChangeListener`? You can always put some prints in those to log whatever you need.

Comment: I hoped a better solution exist, but if I can't find better, I try a base view and do it with listeners. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to log? Id of clicked component or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a Listener at your top most component container and in all his children. The solution is provided by Artur Gajowy on this website http://www.thingsandstuff.eu/2015/04/vaadin-global-event-listener-for.html